# How to install Percona Server on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian, database, apt

I followed the instructions on this [page](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server:release:start):

```
~$ gpg --keyserver  hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
gpg: requesting key CD2EFD2A from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key CD2EFD2A: public key "Percona MySQL Development Team <mysql-dev@percona.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

So far so good. But the next command gave an error:

```
~$ gpg -a --export CD2EFD2A | apt-key add -
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `-': general error
gpg: import from `-' failed: general error
```

What went wrong?

Also after I'm done with this, how exactly do I install Percona Server? There are many [packages](http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.1/Percona-Server-5.1.51-11.5/deb/karmic/i686/) for Karmic and I don't know what to do.

I'm new to this and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `apt-key` as the user `root`. For your second command, try

```
gpg -a --export CD2EFD2A | sudo apt-key add -
```

Actually, it appears that the install instructions assume you are typing all your commands as the `root` user (note the prompt is a `#`). You may want to start over again, but first get a `root` prompt by running this:

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Now that I got the key, how do I actually install the Percona Server? Thanks again.

Comment: I assume you can follow the guide you linked to in your original question. Since you have already imported the repository key, you can begin after that point. And remember, you need to be `root`, so begin your session with `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is also directly available from the Percona website.
Import it as following:

```
wget -O - http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/RPM-GPG-KEY-percona | gpg --import
gpg --armor --export 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A | apt-key add -
```

---

Edit: Percona is going to change their SSH key before the end of this year.
See instructions on their website http://www.percona.com/ssh-key-rotation/instructions